# Supervisord - program number as a parameter

Tags: supervisord

I have a set of programs managed by `supervisord`. There is a program, let's call it `myprogram`, which I need to run in 15 instances. That's easy with the `numprocs` parameter.

Is there a way to pass the process number as a command line agrument to the program, so that each instance is aware of its number?

I need to achieve the same thing as if I run in command line:

```
$ myprogram 1
$ myprogram 2
$ myprogram 3
$ myprogram 4
....
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in your 'command' parameter in your config, you can use %(process_num)d, eg

```
command=myprogram %(process_num)d
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also  use an envionment variable:
like this:

```
environment=num=%(process_num)02d
```

You can then use a getenv() function to get the process number. I usually prefer this method because I prefere reserving parameters to fonctional matters.